# When do positive operators have eigenvalues?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-lattices

Let $B$ be a complex Banach lattice and let $T : B \to B$ be a positive operator. Are there any conditions that ensure that $T$ has an eigenvalue? I am interested in particular in non-compact operators.

I'm interested in the following setting for instance: Denote by $S^1$ the unit circle and we consider operators $T: L^2(S^1) \to L^2(S^1)$. We know that $T$ maps positive functions to positive functions and we also know that $T$ is selfadjoint and satisfies $\langle T f,f \rangle \geq 0$ for all $f\in L^2(S^1)$. However, my operator is not compact. Can we impose some further conditions on $T$ such that we can conclude that $T$ has an eigenvalue? I would be even more interested in an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $||T||$.

Edit after further comments: Even more concretely, I am interested in the following operator. Consider the $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ action on $S^1$, where we view $S^1$ as the boundary of hyperbolic space and denote by $(\rho, L^2(S^1))$ the quasiregular representation associated to this action. Let $\mu$ be a finitely supported probability measure on $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Then the operator I care about is $\rho(\mu) : L^2(S^1) \to L^2(S^1)$.

Comment: In infinite dimensions, the relation between positivity and the existence of eigenvalues is quite subtle. In the general setting that you are describing, note much can be said. Hence, it would be helpful if you could specify a bit more information, for instance: (i) What type of spaces are you interested in? For instance, reflexive spaces, or $L^1$-spaces, or spaces of continuous functions? (ii) Do you suspect that your operator, while not being compact, has smaller essential spectrum than spectrum? (In the latter case, positivity can sometimes help to prove such a claim.)

Comment: By the way, I'm not completely sure whether I understand your question correctly: In the title you ask for the existence of eigenvalues, but in the question itself you ask for the existence of discrete spectrum. Could you specifiy which definition of *discrete spectrum* you use?

Comment: Just made my question more concrete. By discrete spectrum I simply meant the set of eigenvalues.

Comment: The (second) positivity assumption is useless because it is always satisfied by $T+c$, for any operator $T$ as above, if you just take $c\ge \|T\|$.

Comment: Multiplication by a positive function satisfies all the conditions you state. Do you have some structure in mind which excludes this obvious example?

Comment: To be even more precise, I am interested in the following operator. Consider the $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ action on $S^1$, where we view $S^1$ as the boundary of hyperbolic space and denote by $(\rho, L^2(S^1))$ the quasiregular representation associated to this action. Let $\mu$ be a finitely supported probability measure on $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Then the operator I care about is $\rho(\mu) : L^2(S^1) \to L^2(S^1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one result that could, sometimes, be helpful in the setting of the question:

**Theorem.** Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and let $0 \not= T: L^2(\Omega,\mu) \to L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ be a positive (in the sense of Banach lattices) and self-adjoint linear operator. Assume moreover that $T$ is *hyperbounded*, i.e., that there exists a number $q \in (2,\infty)$ such that the range of $T$ is contained in $L^q(\Omega,\mu)$. Then the norm of $T$ (which is equal to the spectral radius of $T$) is an isolated spectral value spectral value of $T$ and an eigenvalue of finite mulitplicity.

This is a consequence of (a more general result in) Corollary 2.4 of my paper "*Spectral gaps for hyperbounded operators* (2020)" [[Link to journal](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2019.106958), [Link to arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.09422)] - but the main idea of this result goes back to much earlier papers of Martínez and Lotz (please see the references in the linked paper for details).

Note, however, that the conclusion of the theorem is stronger than what the question is asking for: the theorem does not only yield an eigenvalue, but also a spectral gap (i.e., the spectral radius is isolated in the spectrum). Hence, the assumptions of theorem are so strong that the theorem can, sometimes, not be applied, even if $\|T\|$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

*Further versions of the theorem:*

- In [op. cit., Sections 2 and 4.1] you can find more results of this type, along with several references.
- In [op. cit., Section 4.2] you can find results where positivity of the operator is replaced with certain contractivity assumptions.

Comment: Interesting - many thanks! In the case that interests me the condition is unfortunately not satisfied and if one could prove a spectral gap that would be a very interesting result that is likely to be not achievable by such general methods. Are you aware of any other results of a similar type that might only focus on proving the existence of an eigenvalue?

Comment: @ConstantinK: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, I am not aware of general methods to show the existence of eigenvalues without spectral gaps. A lot has certainly been done in this direction for stochastic operators on $L^1$ (in the context of Markov chains), but I don't know to what extent this problem has been studied for self-adjoint operators on $L^2$-spaces (without any a priori assumption that the operator be stochastic in any sense). Concering the more specific setting in your edit: I guess I can't be of much help here, since this is not my field of expertise.